# Pass Additional value to Android GCM onRegistered method

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to pass additional value to GCM `onRegistered` method, because I want to check if user is unregistered and then I want to call `GCMRegistrar.register(RegistrationActivity.this, SENDER_ID);` and pass existing user id to `onRegistered` method. So my question is how to pass an additional value so I can get that value in `onRegistered`.

```
package bd.org.basis.projectmanagement;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import static bd.org.basis.projectmanagement.RegistrationActivity.SENDER_ID;;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onMessage", "See later");
        String title=intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String type=intent.getStringExtra("type");
        String msg=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        String url=intent.getStringExtra("url");

        Log.e("onMessage", title+"--"+type+"--"+msg+"-- "+url);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String token) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onRegistered", token);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String token) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: im not getting what you trying to achieve. Sounds like you want to check if a user is registered inside the method that registers a user!?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a parameter to onRegistered,  since you can't change the signature of a method you are overriding.

Why do you want to do it? Do you want onRegistered to be called when the app is already registered?  Calling GCMRegistrar.register will do that, and if the app is already registered,  the existing registration id will be passed to onRegistered anyway,  so you don't need a new parameter.